# inputs without type in system verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I've encountered in an example for a system verilog code decleration of inputs and outputs for a `module` without stating their type, e.g `logic`, `wire`...

```
module mat_to_stream (
  input [2:0] [2:0] [2:0] a,b,
  input newdata,
  input rst, clk,
  output [2:0] [7:0] A_out, B_out);
  ...rest of code...
```

What is the diffrence between stating `logic` and not stating any type?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no difference between stating `logic` and not stating any type.

```
input newdata,
```

is equivalent to

```
input logic newdata,
```

The SystemVerilog IEEE Std (1800-2009) describes this in section: "23.2.2.3 Rules for determining port kind, data type and direction".

Comment: Actually, `input newdata,` is equivalent to `input wire logic newdata,`. `logic` is a data type, and `wire` is a signal kind with a default data type of `logic`.

Answer (score 2):

It is very common to not assign inputs a data type, as they should almost always be `wire`.

```
input [7:0] newdata
```

Is nominally equivalent to:

```
input wire [7:0] newdata
```

It is actually picking up `` `default_nettype wire `` which could be changed to say `uwire` to enforce compiler checks for unique drivers, which will fail on wiring mistakes with multiple drives.

Using `logic` as a type allows the auto selection between `wire` and `reg` which is useful for outputs and allows easier refracting. Inputs can never be `reg` type.

[Stuart Sutherlands SNUG2013 paper](http://www.sutherland-hdl.com/papers/2013-SNUG-SV_Synthesizable-SystemVerilog_paper.pdf), section 12 covers how `uwire` could be used to better imply design intent if it was supported correctly by the tools.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

From, SystemVerilog IEEE Std (1800-2017) describes this in section: "23.2.2.3 Rules for determining port kind, data type and direction"