# Difference of SystemVerilog data types (reg, logic, bit)

Tags: system-verilog

There are different data types in SystemVerilog that can be used like the following:

```
reg   [31:0] data;
logic [31:0] data;
bit   [31:0] data;
```

How do the three of them differ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`reg` and `wire` were the original types. Wires are constantly assigned and regs are evaluated at particular points, the advantage here is for the simulator to make optimisations.

```
wire w_data;
assign w_data = y;

// Same function as above using reg
reg r_data;
always @* 
  r_data = y ;
```

A common mistake when learning Verilog is to assume the a reg type implies a register in hardware. The earlier optimisation for the simulator can be done through the context of its usage.

This introduces `logic` which can be used in place of wire and reg.

```
logic  w_data;
assign w_data = y;

// Same function as above using reg
logic r_data;
always @* 
  r_data = y ;
```

The type `bit` and `byte` have also been created that can only hold 2 states 0 or 1 no x or z. `byte` implies `bit [7:0]`. Using these types offers a small speed improvement but I would recommend not using them in RTL as your verification may miss uninitialized values or critical resets.

The usage of `bit` and `byte` would be more common in testbench components, but can lead to issues in case of having to drive x's to stimulate data corruption and recovery.

---

**Update**

At the time of writing I was under the impression that `logic` could not be used for tristate, I am unable to find the original paper that I based this on. Until further updates, comments or edits, I revoke my assertion that *logic can not be used to create tri-state lines*.

---

The `tri` type has been added, for explicitly defining a tri-state line. It is based on the properties of a `wire`, `logic` is based on the properties of a `reg`.

```
tri t_data;
assign t_data = (drive) ? y : 1'bz ;
```

If you no longer have to support backwards compatibility Verilog then I would recommend switching to using `logic` and `tri`. Using `logic` aids re-factoring and and `tri`  reflects the design intent of a tristate line.

Comment: Look at [this other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33580513/how-do-i-implement-a-parametrizable-mux-in-systemverilog) to see one case where logic cannot be used in the same place as wire.  Look at the comments.

Answer (score 7):

- The choice of the name `reg` [turned out to be a mistake](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11234968/86967), because the existence of registers is instead inferred based on how assignments are performed.  Due to this, use of `reg` is essentially deprecated in favor of `logic`, which is actually the same type.
- `logic` is a 1-bit, 4-state data type
- `bit` is a 1-bit, 2-state data type which may simulate faster than `logic`
- If a `logic` is also declared as a `wire`, it has the additional capability of supporting multiple drivers.  Note that by default `wire` is equivalent to `wire logic`.
- In general, the "[nets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9975415/what-does-net-stand-for-in-verilog)" (such as `wire` and `tri`) are most suitable for designing communication buses.

Practically speaking, for [RTL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register-transfer_level) it usually doesn't matter whether you declare with `reg`, or `logic`, or `wire`.  However, if you have to make an explicit declaration of a 4-state type (as opposed to [when you don't](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5514923/86967)), you should typically choose `logic` since that is what is intended by the language.

---

Related articles:

- [What’s the deal with those wire’s and reg’s in Verilog](https://blogs.mentor.com/verificationhorizons/blog/2013/05/03/wire-vs-reg/)
- [An analysis of the "logic" data type by Cliff Cummings - 20021209](http://www.eda.org/sv-bc/hm/att-0238/01-Logic_20021209.PDF)

Comment: The second link under "Related articles" is dead :(

Comment: Updated link: https://www.accellera.org/images/eda/sv-bc/att-0238/01-Logic_20021209.PDF

Answer (score 2):

As I'm unable to add a comment I've to write what looks like a new answer but isn't. Sigh!

@e19293001, @Morgan, `logic` defines a 4-state variable unlike `bit`, and hence a `logic` variable can be used to store `1'bz` so the following code is valid and compiles:

```
logic t_data;
assign t_data = (drive) ? y : 1'bz ;
```

But I agree that to reflect the design intent `tri` should be used instead of `logic` in these cases (although I must say I don't see people using `tri` instead of `logic`/`wire` too often).

Comment: I am aware that logic holds 4 values (0,1,z,x) but was sure there was an issue with using it for tri-state. I can not find the paper or section in the LRM which says this. I think you might be correct, logic could be used to drive tri state.

Answer (score 0):

reg and logic are exactly the same. These data types appear inside the always or initial blocks and store values i.e. always @(a) b <= a;, the reg b gets evaluated only when 'a' changes but otherwise it simply stores the value it has been assigned last.

wire are just simply connections and need to continuously driven. I agree that they can behave identical as @Morgan mentioned, but they can be imagined as a piece of hard wire, the value of which changes only the value at the other end or the source changes.

Answer (score 0):

> How do the three of them differ?

There is no difference between `logic` and `reg`.

The difference between `bit` and the other two is that `bit` is 2-state, whereas `logic`/`reg` are 4-state.

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 6.11.2, *2-state (two-value) and 4-state (four-value) data types*:

> **logic** and **reg** denote the same type.

Also, section 6.3.1 *Logic values*:

```
The SystemVerilog value set consists of the following four basic values:
0 —represents a logic zero or a false condition
1 —represents a logic one or a true condition
x —represents an unknown logic value
z —represents a high-impedance state
```

> Several SystemVerilog data types are 4-state types, which can store
> all four logic values. All bits of 4-state vectors can be
> independently set to one of the four basic values. Some SystemVerilog
> data types are 2-state, and only store 0 or 1 values in each bit of a
> vector.

Answer (score -1):

Logic data type doesn't permit multiple driver. The last assignment wins in case of multiple assignment .Reg/Wire data type give X if multiple driver try to drive them with different value. Logic data type simply assign the last assignment value.

Answer (score -2):

The "Reg" data type is used in procedural assignment, whereas the "Logic" data type can be used anywhere.

Comment: This answer is incorrect, as this [simulation on edaplayground proves](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/cagK).  Also, Reg and Logic must not be capitalized.