# When exactly to use logic data type and when bit data type in system verilog?

Tags: system-verilog

I know that logic is a 4-state and bit is 2 state, using bit will make to lose testing of x and z. But when exactly bit and when logic?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference of SystemVerilog data types (reg, logic, bits)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13282066/difference-of-systemverilog-data-types-reg-logic-bits)

Answer (score 0):

This paper should cover your questions:

http://www.sutherland-hdl.com/papers/2013-DVCon_In-love-with-my-X_paper.pdf

TLDR;
bit is better for performance (only 2 states to model), but hides [X-propagation](http://www.techdesignforums.com/practice/guides/x-propagation/) issues.